# Randomly select a list element only once when loading a scene (multiple times)

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, singleton, game-development

I'm developing a VR mini game in which the user looks for objects inside a room. At the center of the scene there is something like a tv screen, where an image of the to-be-searched object is being displayed. So, at the beginning the user takes a look at the tv screen to see which object they have to look for. Then, they start searching within the room for this object. Once they find it, they have to press the trigger button and the same scene is reloaded. After reloading, a new object is being displayed on the tv screen. This goes on until the user searches for all the objects at least once.

What I have until now is shown below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class TrialHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static TrialHandler Instance;
    public List<GameObject> objectsList;
    private int currentObject;
    private float timer;
    [HideInInspector] public static int trialNum = 0;

    private void Awake()
    {
        objectsList = objectsList.Where(item => item != null).ToList();
        if (Instance = null)
        {
            Instance = this;
        }
        else if (Instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        currentObject = Random.Range(0, objectsList.Count);
        objectsList[currentObject].SetActive(true);
        trialNum += 1;
    }

    void Update()
    {
      timer += Time.deltaTime;
      if (timer >= 3.0f)
      {
           objectsList.RemoveAt(currentObject);
           objectsList[currentObject].SetActive(false);
      }
    }
```

On the tv screen, images of the to-be-searched objects are being displayed. All these images are present in the scene but deactivated. When the scene starts, I select one image randomly and activate it. This way an image of the to-be-searched object is being displayed and prompts the user on which object to look for.

I have several problems:

1. Although the list becomes populated the first time the scene loads, from the second load onwards the list elements in the inspector are empty ( "Missing (GameObject)"). However, the images are being displayed properly each time I reload the scene.
2. Despite the fact that I am trying to get rid off the image(s) that were previously selected, so they don't get displayed again, I don't get it right. Random images are getting displayed each time, but this means that some might appear 2 or 3 times, instead of 1.

Any advice would be very much welcomed.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is the purpose of this line: `objectsList = objectsList.Where(item => item != null).ToList();`? Why would you have any null objects assigned in the inspector?

Comment: What do you want to do with that `timer`? Is it supposed to deactivate the image after 3 seconds? Because it does not.

Comment: Hi @Bamdad. Yes, my intention was to deactivate the image after 3 seconds. Any pointers on how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the big indicator of what the problem is: ***However, the images are being displayed properly each time I reload the scene.***

What lines of code are making the script behave differently between loads?

```
        if (Instance = null)
        {
            Instance = this;
        }
        else if (Instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
```

You've got a singleton! That's perfectly fine, but something to remember with this pattern is that the first load of this script is the only one that will persist through the life of your game. All future sceneloads will create their own instance of this script, but will destroy itself before it can perform logic.

This means `Start()` will not run on any future loads of the scene, because the original script is the one that is still active. Your intended behavior is unclear here so I can't provide exact code, but you'll likely want to move your `Start()` logic elsewhere to ensure it runs every time it loads.

You're likely not accessing the correct objectList. I don't see any references to the instance here, and can't draw a conclusion based on what you have here.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. If Start() won't run on any future loads of the scene, then why do I get a different random object every time I reload the scene? The code for random object selection is in the Start() and seems to be working fine.

Comment: I used a singleton pattern because I wanted to keep track of which images were shown in previous scene loads so that I don't show them again. So, I randomly pick an object from the list and activate it in the scene, then after 3 seconds I deactivate it and remove it from the list...

Comment: When I load a new scene, I would expect that this image would not be part of the list and another random image (from the remaining ones) would be picked.

Comment: When you load a new scene, the original class is still active and already ran start. @Phoenix